# Oozie : How to resolve Error: HTTP error code: 302: Moved Temporarily

Tags: oozie

when I run a oozie, the command is

```
oozie job -run \
-config ${launcher_root}/conf/conf.properties \
-oozie ${pathofserver} \
-Doozie_app_path=${root_app_path} \
-Doozie.coord.application.path=${app_path_of_coordinator_xml}
```

The paths are all right.
And the error code is:

> Error: HTTP error code: 302 : Moved Temporarily

Comment: There should be some additional logs into oozie.log. Please check. Thanks.